# monaca で jQuery の $ が使えない

Tags: monaca

プログラム初心者です。色々調べたのですが分からなかった為こちらで質問致しました。
ご教授お願い出来ないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

ピンチイン・ピンチアウトをしたいのでmonacaでHammer.jsを使おうとしています。
JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加から「Hammer.js」を選択し、`hammer.min.js`をロードするように設定しました。
いろいろなエラーが出て、それを修正しているうちに、なぜか`$`関数の呼び出しに失敗するようになってしまいました。

```
Uncaught TypeError:Propetty '$'of object [object Object]is not a function
```

`console.log("what is $:", $)`としたところ何も入っていませんでした。

---

なぜ動かないのか自分なりに色々調べてみたのですが、そもそもプラグインがきちんと読み込まれていない？かもしれません。理由がよく分かりません(もしかすると自分のミスかもしれませんが・・)
表題からはずれてしまうのですが、一旦Hammer.jsを置いて、別のプラグインで簡単に動かしてみました。

- 使用したプラグイン⇒d3.js
- d3.jsプラグインはmonacaのJS/CSSコンポーネントの追加から行いました。
  　(表示されたもの全てをダウンロードしました。)

これはうまく行き、d3が動作する事を確認出来ました。

---

現在のプログラムを全て記載致します。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">


    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="components/hammer.min.js"></script>   

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <script>
        $(function() {　　←ここでエラーが出ています。
            //Hammer.jsオブジェクトの読み込み
            var $exampleElm = document.getElementById("example"),
                $hammerObj = new Hammer($exampleElm),
                $jqExampleElm = $($exampleElm);
                $hammerObj.get("pan").set({ enable: true });
                $hammerObj.get("pinch").set({ enable: true });
                $hammerObj.get("tap").set({ enable: true });
                $hammerObj.get("swipe").set({ enable: true });

            //pan event
                $hammerObj.on("pan",function(event) {
                    if(event.isFinal) { //end
                        panTime = false;
                        $jqTgPanPinchArea.data("down", false);
                        //パンが終わったときの操作
                    } else {
                        if(!panTime) { //start
                            $jqExampleElm.data("down", true);
            　　　　　　　　//パンを始めたときの動作
                        } else { //move
                            if ($jqExampleElm.data("down") == true) {
                                //パンしている途中の動作
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                var panTime = false,
                    pinchTime = false,
                    $pinchTimer = {};

            //pinch event
                $hammerObj.on("pinch",function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
                    if(!pinchTime) { //start
                        pinchTime = event.timeStamp;
                        //ピンチを始めたときの動作
                    } else { //move
                        if($pinchTimer) clearTimeout($pinchTimer);
                        //ピンチをしている途中の動作
                        $pinchTimer = setTimeout(function() { //end
                            pinchTime = false;
                            //ピンチが終わったときの動作
                        }, 100);
                    }
                });
                 $hammerObj.on("tap", function(event) {
                    //タップしたときの動作
                });
                //swipe
                $hammerObj.on("swipeleft", function(event) {
                    //左へスワイプした時の動作
                });
                $hammerObj.on("swiperight", function(event) {
                    //右へスワイプした時の動作
                });


        });

        </script>
```

bodyタグの中にdivでid='example'としています。

---

修正して解決したエラー:

#### www/components/loader.jsのエラー

> `(Uncaught ReferenceError:require is not defined)`
>   `var changelog = require( "changelogplease" );`←ここで引っかかっているみたいです。

これは、changelog のロードを止めて hammer.min.js のみにして解決。

#### index.htmlのエラー

> `(Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token ILLEGAL)`
>   `$jqExampleElm = $($exampleElm)；`　　←ここでエラーが出ます。

これは、「；」が全角だったのを直して解決。

#### hammer.min.js のエラー

> `Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method'addEventListener'of null`と出ています。

これは、HTML側に要素を用意して解決。
このエラーが出た時点では、**jQueryもHammerも動いていた**事になります。

Comment: 質問では `；` が全角の文字になっていますが、実際にもそうですか？

Comment: 初歩的なミスごめんなさい。「;」を半角にしたのですがまだエラーが出ます。今度は１行前の $hammerObj = new Hammer($exampleElm),にて(Uncaught ReferenceError:require is not defined)というエラーが出ました。。

Comment: 追記されたコードは最初ののコードとどのように繋がっていますか？ `$hammerObj`は最初のコードの無名関数(`$`に渡されるもの)で定義されていますから、同じ関数内でないと参照出来ません。

Comment: エラーがどうしても出てしまいます。追記2に記載しているのが現状です。

Comment: もしかして、「ローダーの設定」のところで jQuery のロードもはずしていますか？ 私の回答が誤解を招いたかもしれませんが、jQuery などの他のパッケージは使用するならば、ロードする必要があります。

Comment: @mjyさん　「ローダーの設定」のところでjQueriは読み込んでいます。monacaの「JS/CSSコンポーネントの追加と削除」からｊQueri(Monaca version)を入れているので読み込んでいる・・・はずです。

Comment: `console.log("what is $:", $)` などとして`$`が何になっているか確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。エラーとは関係ないと思いますが、`<script src="components/hammer.min.js">`は必要ないと思います。これを自動でやるのが Monaca の `loader.js` のようですから。

Comment: `d3`が動いていないように見えるのは、コードを`<head>`の中の`<script>`に入れているからです。この時点では DOM に `body` 以下の要素が作成されていませんから、`selectAll`で何も選択されないのです。`<body>`の末尾（少なくとも`<p>`より後）にコードを置けば動くはずです。

Comment: 初心者で本当に申し訳ありません。ご指摘の通りにしたところ動きました！ありがとうございます。勉強致します。。

Comment: 話が前後して申し訳ないのですが、console.log("what is $:", $)としたところ何も入っていませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`changelog`が何なのか確認していませんが、クライアントサイドで使用する物ではないかもしれません。
「ローダーの設定」でロードするものを`hammer.js`か`hammer.min.js`のみにしてみて下さい。

Comment: 「ローダーの設定」でロードするものをhammer.min.jsのみにしましたが、エラーが出ます。。

Comment: @R.R  現在出ているエラーはどれでしょうか。

Comment: hammer.min.jsでエラーが出ています。

Comment: Uncaught TypeError:Cannot call method'addEventListener'of nullと出ています。

Comment: @R.R  id が `example`である要素を HTML 側で用意していますか？

Comment: 何度もご返信頂きありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、用意していませんでした。<body id='example'>としたことで今までのエラーはなくなったのですが、新しいエラーが出てしまいました。追記で記載した箇所です。